# How to get the first value for each distinct keys using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, email, java-8, java-stream

For example: I have a list of user objects with e-mails. I would like to collect the list of users with distinct e-mails (because two users with the same e-mail would be probably the same person, so I do not care about the differences). In other words, for each distinct key (e-mail), I want to grab the first value (user) found with that key and ignore the rest.

This is a code I have came up with:

```
public List<User> getUsersToInvite(List<User> users) {
    return users
            .stream()
            // group users by their e-mail
            // the resulting map structure: email -> [user]
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getEmail, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
            // browse each map entry
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            // get the first user object for each entry
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue().get(0))
            // collect such first entries into a list
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Is there some more elegant way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), use the e-mail as key, user as value and ignore the key conflicts by always returning the first value. From the `Map`, you can then get the users by calling [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--).

```
public List<User> getUsersToInvite(List<User> users) {
    return new ArrayList<>(users.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getEmail, 
                                                          Function.identity(), 
                                                          (u1, u2) -> u1))
                                .values());
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to be sure: is Collectors.toMap causing always the first value for each key to be selected? I believe that you have to use LinkedHashMap explicitly as the default collector can shift the order of elements randomly. At least in my code sample. I fixed it there.

Comment: @voho the stream returned by `List.stream()` is sequential and `Collectors.toMap` preserve the encountering order of the elements so, yes, this will always cause the first value in the List to be kept.

Comment: @Tunaki where do you see in the docs that the first parameter of the merge function is the old value and the second parameter is the new value? I can't find it explicitly in the docs anywhere.

All it says is:
"mergeFunction - a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key, as supplied to Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)"

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)